# Excel lookup in list of substrings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula in MS Excel to check if a cell, containing a sentence, matches (at least) one substring in a given range, **and if it does, return that substring-value**.

I can best explain it using following example. If the sentence (on the right) contains one of the fruits defined in the table (on the left), the result should **return the (first) matching fruit**:

[image: New example]

Preferable, the lookup function should be case insensitive. Also, it is not possible for me to use VBA - it would need to be performed using Excel-native functions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will there be only 1 substring in each sentence? If not, how do you want to handle multiple matches?

Comment: Yes, normally, the substrings will be complex enough so that only one substring would occur in each sentence. In case multiple would occur, it is fine to just return the first found result (similar to VLOOKUP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SEARCH` for that, in an array formula. Then use `INDEX` and `MATCH` with the results of `SEARCH`:

```
=INDEX(Substrings, MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Substrings, Sentence)), 0))
```

Since it's an array formula, you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing out the formula instead of pressing only <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<s>EDIT: I forgot to mention that the above formula is case sensitive. Thanks jblood94 for mentioning it. The following formula uses `LOWER` to make  it case insensitive.</s>

```
=INDEX(Substrings, MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LOWER(Substrings), LOWER(Sentence))), 0))
```

Comment: Nice. You could make it case-insensitive by adding `LOWER` or `UPPER` to Substrings and Sentence inside `SEARCH`

Comment: @jblood94 Ah, I actually intended to, then forgot about it somewhere along the way....

Comment: Thank you for this! I was looking in the same direction, but didn't know you could provide a list of substrings to SEARCH without using SUMPRODUCT. To my knowledge, SEARCH is case-insensitive so LOWER/UPPER is not needed.

I do have a weird problem though of always returning the first value of my substring-list, but will look further into this.

Comment: @AdFundum Welp this is embarassing xD Yup, `FIND` is the one that is case sensitive!

Comment: @Jerry There does seem to be some malfunctioning in my code or in the formula. When I try the formula on my example, it always returns the last result: https://imgur.com/a/WS2urnr

Comment: @AdFundum There is one misplaced part in your formula. The `;0` should not be inside `SEARCH()`, but inside `MATCH()`

Comment: @Jerry You are absolutely right - my turn to embarrass myself haha. Thank you again for all your help, everything working beautifully now!

Comment: nvm i fixed it... messed the formula up